# Find server with small ping latency (my script, but can anyone write it in e.g.: Perl?)

Tags: linux, openbsd, perl

I want to download OpenBSD with FTP with a script, and I want to download it from a server that is near me. So I want to choose a mirror that has low "ping latency". I wrote a little script, that works just fine (only tested under bash/Linux):

```
LATESTRELVER=`curl -s 'www.openbsd.org' | fgrep 'The current release is ' | sed 's/OpenBSD /\n/' | sed 's/<\/a>/\n/' | grep "^[0-9]" | head -1`
FASTESTSRV=`curl -s "http://www.openbsd.org/ftp.html#ftp" | fgrep '<a href="ftp://' | sed 's/"ftp:\/\//\n/' | cut -d "/" -f1 | fgrep -v '<a href=' | while read MIRRORSRVS; do ping -c 1 -w 1 $MIRRORSRVS 2>/dev/null | fgrep ' time=' | sed 's/ time=/\n/' | grep ' ms' | sed 's/ ms$/ /' | sed 's/\./ |/' | cut -d "|" -f1 | tr -d '\n'; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "$MIRRORSRVS"; fi; done | grep "^[0-9]" | sort -un | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
LATESTRELVERSHORT=`echo $LATESTRELVER | sed 's/\.//g'`

# NEEDEDARCH=i386
NEEDEDARCH=amd64

wget "$FASTESTSRV/pub/OpenBSD/$LATESTRELVER/$NEEDEDARCH/install$LATESTRELVERSHORT.iso" -O "install$LATESTRELVERSHORT-$NEEDEDARCH.iso"
```

Q: can someone write this script in Perl? :P (with a smaller, nicer code?)

The main purpose of this script to e.g.: not use foreign country's bandwidth.

Comment: ping measures latency, not throughput. Thus it is useless for comparing ftp servers.

Comment: that's fully true, but the lower the ping the nearer the server is. I don't want to use servers what are too far away...on a foreign land

Comment: Trust us on this one, you don't care where an ftp server is if it gives you better throughput. The only exception would be if you pay for bandwidth differently depending on where it's coming from, but at your level of the networking world that is probably an irrelevant factor. Throughput is the metric you want to use, not ping times! If this was about something other than FTP, you could make a case for round trip times, but ftp is about file transfer. If all yours files are tiny you should reconsider not having used `tar`!

Comment: *"Q: can someone write this script in Perl? :P (with a smaller, nicer code?)"* this is not ontopic and not a real question.

Comment: It would be closed on stackoverflow even because you're asking someone to do your work for you. If you were to put some effort into writing it in perl, and got stuck, then you could ask this on stackoverlow.

Comment: fping did the trick

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to select some suitable mirrors is with [netselect](http://apenwarr.ca/netselect/index.html).  You can use the `-s 3` option to tell it to pick the 3 best servers.